# Custom HttpHandler is never loaded in IIS 10

Tags: http-status-code-404, httphandler, iis-10

We're moving a site to a new server, and running into an issue with a custom HTTP Handler. The old server was IIS 6.1, the new server is IIS 10 (Server 2019).

The handler is meant to handle all requests under a certain directory path (which does **not** physically exist on disc), and retrieve the requested files from Sql Server, where they are stored as bytes. The handler itself is super simple; while I don't think it is relevant, here is the code for the handler, which is located in the `App_Code` folder.

```vb
Public Class GetCaseUpload
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim url = context.Request.Url
        Dim guid = url.Segments()(url.Segments.Length - 2).Trim("/".ToCharArray())

        Dim dbo = GetDbObj()
        Dim data = dbo.ExecuteDR(<s>SELECT * FROM dbo.UPLOADS WHERE GUID = <%= dbo.FixString(guid) %></s>)
        If data Is Nothing Then
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            context.Response.Write("The requested upload could not be found." & vbCrLf & "GUID: " & guid)
        Else
            context.Response.ContentType = data("FILETYPE")
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(data("FILEBYTES"))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The pipeline is running in integrated mode. Here is the current Handler mapping in `system.webServer`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
        <add name="GetCaseUploadFile" path="*/cases/uploads/*" verb="GET" type="GetCaseUpload" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        ... others removed for brevity ...
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I just flat-out deleted the handler entries from the old server, and readded it through the **Add Managed Handler** dialog in the `Handler Mappings` section of the site in IIS management console, and that is what it created.

Also, since these files are not ones normally handled by IIS (PDF, JPGs, DOCs, etc.), I've tried adding

```xml
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Although it was working on the old server without needing that.

Any time I try to pull up a file from that directory though, it always returns a 404.0 error, and shows that the request was mapped to the Static File handler. I've turned on Failed Request Tracing, and see the logs for the requests, and nowhere in the details does it ever even mention that it loaded my handler. If I search through the raw XML file, the name of my class is not found at all.

Here is the detailed error screen being shown: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the handler code in web.config file as suggested in the below section:

```
<handlers>
<add name="MyHandler" verb="*" path="myhandler.api" type="MyAssembly.MyHandlerClass, MyAssembly"/>
</handlers>
```

If your application pool running in Classic mode, then the handler reference needs to go into the following section:

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="myhandler.api" type="MyAssembly.MyHandlerClass, MyAssembly"/>
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

If your application pool running in Integrated pipelined mode, then the handler reference needs to go into the following section:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="MyHandler" verb="*" path="myhandler.api" type="MyAssembly.MyHandlerClass, MyAssembly"/>
</handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

so first check your application pool mode and set the handler code.

Comment: The pipeline is running in integrated mode, and as stated, I have the handler in the `handlers` section. I added more of the code to make that clearer.

Comment: is requested path is available at your machine? it looks like the requested file is not available at the place. try to use failed request tracing [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: Correct. As stated, the file and folder do **not** physically exist on the server. That is the point of the handler, the whole reason for it. It is registered to that subdirectory, and when a file is requested from that directory, it loads the file from a byte stream in the database, and streams it down to the client. This works fine on our older servers, on numerous sites, but not - apparently - on Server 2019. Which is what I was hoping to find a fix for. MS obviously changed something in IIS.

Comment: you need to provide a full path of the handler and make sure you assign proper permission to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Service that implements IHttpHandler running fine on IIS 6 migrated to IIS 10 and needed to work out the required config tweak in order to overcome migrated service getting 404.

Answer provided by Jalpa Panchal did the trick.